# Incorrect ng-class output Jasmine Test Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm testing an Angular Directive where I use $compile to create an instance of the directive in the DOM.  The markup for the element which the directive is attached to uses an ng-class with an expression inside.  The special characters for that expression are being turned into their "safe" equivalents.

```
<article my-directive
    ng-class="(selectedItems.length > 1 && asset.selected === true) ? 'class1' : 'class2'">
 </article>
```

Looking at the HTML output by the $compile in the test:

> 'ng-class="(selectedItems.length &gt 1 &amp&amp asset.selected ===
>   true) ? class1: class2"'

Answer (score 0):

This is valid HTML :)

When you $compile() or angular.element() string like this

```
<article my-directive ng-class="(selectedItems.length > 1 &amp;&amp; asset.selected === true) ? 'class1' : 'class2'"></article>
```

yo get proper HTML.

Some play-around with this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ulfryk/vzz3x6py/